# combine two bool queries in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create the equivalent of the following query:

```
(country.id = 2000 AND natureservices.id = 2000 AND metiers.id = 1000) AND (shortname = "shortname" OR fullname = "fullname" OR categories.id = 1000 OR specialities.id = 2000)
```

in my case he must show me a single result but when i tried the below query it show many results

```
{ "query": {
   "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "term": { "country.id": 2000 } },
            { "term": { "natureservices.id": 2000 } },
            { "term": { "metiers.id": 1000 } },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        { "term": { "shortname": "vgftQzSPwW" } },
                        { "term": { "fullname": "qcouWRzFNG" } },
                        { "term": { "categories.id": 1000 } },
                        { "term": { "specialities.id": 2000 } }
                    ], "minimum_should_match": 4
                }
            }
        ], "minimum_should_match": 3
    }
 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query) . I have correct your query literally, but I can't understand why you are using a `minimum_should_match` clause in that way. `minimum_should_match` usually is used when you have more clauses than the number you specify there. For example if you have 4 should clauses, but for some reason you only need three of them to be fulfilled, you would assign 3 as value of `minimum_should_match` . According me this use of `minimum_should_match` could creates problems, so i have expunged `minimum_should_match` from your query. The correct syntax of your query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "country.id": 2000
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "natureservices.id": 2000
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "metiers.id": 1000
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "shortname": "vgftQzSPwW"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "fullname": "qcouWRzFNG"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "categories.id": 1000
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "specialities.id": 2000
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i modify this query according to this condition:  if(valueShortName != null) { shortname =  valueShortName} OR if(valueFullName != null) { fullname = valueFullName }